# _.defaultsDeep() with Vue.set()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

I need to set default values from model to component object in my vue.js application.

I found the perfect solution in lodash defaultsDeep `defaultsDeep(this.widget, this.widgetModel)`, but the values don't get reactive obviously (added props not reactive), so I need something similar to _.defaultsDeep(), but with a callback to vm.$set() OR make all properties of object reactive after set defaults, OR even add defaultsDeepWith function to lodash

I looked to source code of defaultsDeep, but looks like i don't have enough experience to understand that, also i looked to vue-deepset librariy and seems it don't fit to my case (library better fit to stringed properties), also project based on vue.js 2

Comment: You can copy the code of `lodash.defaultsDeep` into your component and put `Vue.$set` or `Vue.observable()` at the relevant places in the code. You may also consider https://github.com/bhoriuchi/vue-deepset or use the new Composition API in Vue v3.

Comment: I looked to source code of defaultsDeep, but looks like i don't have enough experience to understand that, also i looked to vue-deepset librariy and seems it don't fit to my case (library better fit to stringed properties), also project based on vue.js 2

Comment: Hmm, then the only thing left for you to try is building the function yourself - recursively enumerating all properties of the model and making them reactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const defaultsDeepWithSet = (targetObj, sourceObj) => {
  for (let prop in sourceObj) {
    if (sourceObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (!targetObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        this.$set(targetObj, prop, sourceObj[prop])
      }
      if (isObject(sourceObj[prop])) {
        defaultsDeepWithSet(targetObj[prop], sourceObj[prop])
      }
    }
  }
}
defaultsDeepWithSet(this.widget, this.widgetModel)
```

[Obama awards obama a medal meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/obama-awards-obama-a-medal)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same issue with `_.defaultsDeep()` and other similar utils.   If this is a prominent issue and you don't want Vue to bleed into every corner of your codebase, then consider fixing reactivity after the fact.

I happen to be using Vue 2 Composition API, so it looks like this:

```js
import { reactive, isReactive, isRaw } from '@vue/composition-api';

const fixReactivity = (obj) => {
  // Done?
  if (!obj) return obj;
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') return obj;

  // Force reactive
  if (!isReactive(obj)) {
    // See: https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/blob/6247ba3a1e593b297321f68c1b7bb0dee2c3ea1e/src/reactivity/reactive.ts#L43
    const canBeReactive = !(!(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]' || Array.isArray(obj)) || isRaw(obj) || !Object.isExtensible(obj));
    if (canBeReactive) reactive(obj);
  }
  
  const isArray = Array.isArray(obj);
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    // Fix the children
    const val = obj[key];
    fixReactivity(val);
    
    // Fix assignment for objects
    if (!isArray) {
      const prop = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key);
      const needsFix = ('value' in prop) && prop.writable;
      if (needsFix) {
        Vue.delete(obj, key);
        Vue.set(obj, key, val);
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
```